# Interpretation of product of terms in system of differential equations

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, mathematical-modeling

Let $S(t)$ be the number of susceptibles to some disease, $I(t)$ the number of infected individuals and $A(t)$ the number of those who are diseased. Furthermore, let $N(t)=S(t)+I(t)$. The model is as follows:

$$
\frac{dS}{dt} = p\lambda [\epsilon I(t-a)+S(t-a)]-\frac{w(t)SI}{N}-\mu S
$$

$$
\frac{dI}{dt}=\frac{w(t)SI}{N}-(\gamma+\mu)I
$$

$$
\frac{dA}{dt}=\gamma I - (\tau + \mu)A,
$$

where $w(t)$ is the variable force of infection. Currently the other variables aren't important for my question.

I am wondering how to interpret the term $$ -\frac{w(t)SI}{N} $$ in the first equation? Is it the rate at which those who are susceptible get infected?

Comment: The whole of the right hand side is the rate at which the population of susceptibles is increasing. This particular term reflects the fact that as the proportion $\frac IN$'of the infected population increases the actual number of susceptibles decreases at a rate proportional to this and the number of susceptibles not already infected, together with a time dependent weighting $w(t)$

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Law_of_mass_action#In_mathematical_epidemiology